# Create new invoice in XERO after deal was won on MONDAY

Tags: zapier, xero-api, monday.com

Want to create a new invoice in `XERO` automatically after a deal was won on `Monday.com`

The problem is that can't find a specific event for this on `Zapier`.
Or maybe it's possible to do this in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adelak I'm assuming that deal won on monday.com is represented by a status column meaning your trigger should be 'update column value'.
On XERO your action is probably 'create sales invoice'

Answer (score 0):

looks possible to me.. https://zapier.com/apps/monday/integrations/xero

Although yeah I don't see all the endpoints mapped out as options..

Ideally to get that granular monday would need to build their own integration to Xero.

Comment: Thanks, SerKnight. I have seen this, but can't understand what will be the trigger(from Monday.com side) for doing this.